# ReactNative - PermissionDialog after launching app - 'remove' won't work

Tags: react-native, android-permissions

In ReactNative app, we are using Storage permission to view/save pictures. So we're getting runtime permission where its required. But the strange thing is, it was asking permission in Splash screen itself, where we didn't ask permission. Then I came across the following fix:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/removing-default-permissions

**Removing Permission using 'remove':**

```
<uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

But the problem is, If I do like this, I can't get those permissions where its needed.

So ideally, I would like to remove permission dialog in SplashScreen and add only where its required. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

This answer might seems bit odd to you, but I was in same situation, where I need to use Storage Permission of zip extraction in my current application.

The way I manage things are as follows:

1. I asked permission in Android Code using React Native Bridging
   concept.
2. I add delay to show permission dialog on next screen (i.e
   after splash screen)
3. When user grant me permission I started extraction and overlay loader to full screen.
4. When user denied the storage permission I closed the application.

Check the code below

**NextScreen After Splash**

```
this.onZipExtracted = this.onZipExtracted.bind(this)

componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        Splash.hide()
    }, Platform.OS == 'ios' ? 1000 : 500);

    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        AsyncStorage.getItem("Extraction",(error,result)=>{
            if(result != 'done'){
                this.setState({
                    animating:true
                })
                setTimeout(() => {
                    expandPath.callReactMethod(this.onZipExtracted, (error) => {
                        console.log("Activation Inside Callback"+JSON.stringify(error))
//Do your stuff 

                    })
                }, 500)
            }
        })
    }
}

onZipExtracted(success){
    console.log("Activation Callback Extract Success -> "+JSON.stringify(success))
    this.setState({
        set loader flag
    })
    AsyncStorage.setItem("Extraction","done")
    Actions.replace('Screen to replace')
}
```

**Java Code for Permission**

I used Dexter Android Permission Library

```
@ReactMethod
public void callReactMethod(Callback successCallback, Callback errorCallback){
    callUserPermission(getCurrentActivity(), successCallback,errorCallback);
}

private void callUserPermission(Activity currentActivity, Callback successCallback, Callback errorCallback) {
    Dexter.withActivity(getCurrentActivity())
            .withPermissions(
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            .withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport report) {
                    // check if all permissions are granted
                    if (report.areAllPermissionsGranted()) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "onPermissionsChecked: -> Granted");

                         // Do your stuff here
                        }
                    } else {
                        currentActivity.finishAffinity();
                        System.exit(0);
                    }

                    // check for permanent denial of any permission
                    if (report.isAnyPermissionPermanentlyDenied()) {
                        // permission is denied permenantly, navigate user to app setting
                    }
                }


                @Override
                public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> permissions,
                                                               PermissionToken token) {
                    token.continuePermissionRequest();
                }
            })
            .onSameThread()
            .check();
}
```